# Customer Login within Agent Login Instance

Tags: login, customer-account

Is it possible to have an agent login to Magento sales portal and then have customer's login & logout for assisted sales within the Agent's login instance?

Comment: The simple answer is *no*. But please explain the whole process in more detail including what you've tried so far so we can help you better

Comment: Thank you for responding Sander. I haven't really tried anything - I am writing down specs of my e-commerce site and my developer told me that it is not possible. Here is my need - I run retail stores in which I want customers to buy my products using a megento based point of sales solutions(e-commerce site) - for which they shall create their account for updates and communication related to order. At the same time, I want to track the Salesman who makes the sale and registers the user so that the salesman is accountable for the order execution.